# Why is android's Log class static?

Tags: android, logging

Wouldn't it be more convenient to do it like Log4J's Logger class?

Logging in android:

```
private static final String TAG = "MyClass";
...
    Log.d(TAG, "message1");
    Log.d(TAG, "message2");
```

Logging in Log4J:

```
private static final Logger log = Log.getLogger("MyClass");
...
    log.d("message1");
    log.d("message1");
```

Comment: It is less convenient as it comes, I agree. But a wrapper is so easy to do why don't you just make one (static of course).

Comment: I agree a wrapper would be very trivial, but now I'm wondering why I don't see other projects using wrapper...

Answer (score 1):

Though it doesn't really answer your question, may I suggest a logger combining these two approaches? It's a drop-in replacement for android.util.Log, so you can just replace your imports:

https://github.com/zserge/log

```
class SomeClass {
  private final static String TAG = "MyTag";
  ...
  Log.d("Hello"); // 'D/MyTag: Hello' will be printed
  // or if the TAG field is missing - the class name will be used
}
```